# Running single test with TestNG in Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, testng

How do you guys run single tests with IDEA's TestNG plugin? I tried creating a focus group, but it seems the TestNG plugin does not resolve dependencies to other tests automatically. Even when I comment out `dependsOnMethods`, it seems `@BeforeMethod` is not run.

Advice is greatly appreciated,

Robin

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you mean a single test method inside a test class there is a right-click option called `Run "testMethod"` where testMethod is the actual method name.

The short cut is ctrl+shift+F10.

If you put the cursor between methods (even outside the javadoc) or outside the entire class it will test all methods in that file.

Comment: In case that option does not show up: Make sure the class in question is recognized as a _test class_ by IndelliJ IDEA (test classes have a different icon in the project structure tool window). In my case, the class was _package local_ instead of _public_, test class must be public.

Answer (score 1):

Bring the class into focus in the editor, and then simply right-click, select run?

Comment: I meant concrete test methods. I just tested it again, @ BeforeMethod runs when clicking on a single method. However, so do Tests provided with @ Factory and it doesn't work if the test has a (dependsOnMethod= ...) (@Andreas Wederbrand)